# Как лучше всего прописывать путь к файлам и папкам в PHP?

Tags: php

Как лучше всего прописывать путь к файлам и папкам в PHP использую глобальные переменные окружения?

Не первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой - при подключении какого либо файла посредством "require" или "include". Дело в том, что файл подключается относительно какой либо директории и соответственно относительно этой же директории и задается путь к подключаемому файлу. Стоит переместить файл, в котором подключают другой файл в другую папку.. и все - путь не работает. Есть ли способы нахождения пути к подключаемому файлу из любого места на сервере? –

Пример такой есть ссылка Выход (logout.php) на главной странице сайта, но когда мы заходим в админ-панель, то здесь начинаются проблему. Так как админ панель находится в папке /admin/ то ссылка Выход уже выглядит так - /admin/logout.php, но такого файла нет в папке админ. Как избежать дублирования файлов по разным директориям? Как правильно прописать пути с помощью PHP?

Comment: Всем здравствуйте! Не первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой - при подключении какого либо файла посредством "require" или "include". Дело в том, что файл подключается относительно какой либо директории и соответственно относительно этой же директории и задается путь к подключаемому файлу. Стоит переместить файл, в котором подключают другой файл в другую папку.. и все - путь не работает. Есть ли способы нахождения пути к подключаемому файлу из любого места на сервере?

Comment: Пример такой есть ссылка Выход (logout.php) на главной странице сайта, но когда мы заходим в админ-панель, то здесь начинаются проблему. Так как админ панель находится в папке /admin/ то ссылка Выход уже выглядит так - /admin/logout.php, но такого файла нет в папке админ. Как избежать дублирования файлов по разным директориям? Как правильно прописать пути с помощью PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом вопросе перепутаны два разных понятия.

Во втором абзаце упомянуты операторы `require` или `include`, которые работают с **файловой системой.** И искомой переменной окружения для них является `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

А в третьем абзаце говорится о **ссылках на сайте**, которым никакая переменная не нужна, а корневой каталог выглядит очень просто - это обычный слеш - `/`

То есть, чтобы подключить файл, то надо написать

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/logout.php';
```

а если надо дать ссылку на сайте, то просто

```
<a href ="/logout.php">
```

и эти вызовы будут работать, куда бы вызывающий файл ни переместили